# Build multiple versions of a binary with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I want to build two versions of my program, a "normal" version, and one in which the address sanitizer has been activated. As of now, I have this in my `QSoas.pro`

```
sanitizer {
  message("Activating the address sanitizer code")
  OBJECTS_DIR = build-snt
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address
  LIBS += -fsanitize=address
  TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,-snt)
}
```

This way, I can do:

```
~ qmake
~ make
```

to get the normal version, and

```
~ qmake CONFIG+=sanitizer
~ make
```

to get the version with the address sanitizer.

This is fine, but a little cumbersome, especially since I need in fact many other configuration options on the `qmake` command-line. Is there a way to have two targets, so that I could simply run

```
~ qmake
~ make
~ make my-sanitized-exe
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266285/3293508) what you are looking for?

Comment: I am not sure it will work. Just an idea. You might have a set of makefiles, each of which specify its own configuration and call `make` with `-f` option to specify which makefile to use.

Comment: @NguyenCong This is what I'm already doing.

Comment: @vahancho This is indeed a possibility... with the automatic rebuilding of the makefile by qmake, it could actually work. Would you make a full answer with that ?
It looks like a hack, though :-)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural way, IMO, is an out-of-source build. That is, create a subdirectory called "sanitizer", go into it, and build your Makefile(s) the same way you do it with `cmake`, `meson` etc.:

```
mkdir sanitizer
cd sanitizer
qmake CONFIG+=sanitizer ../Qsoas.pro
```

QMake natively supports out-of-source builds, so everything should be fine. However, if you need to distiguish between the source and build directories, you can use the variables `$$PWD` and `$$OUT_PWD`.

See also qmake's manual for [shadowed()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#shadowed-path) function to translate the paths automatically.

Comment: This is neat too, I wasn't aware of this possibility at all.

Comment: @VincentFourmond Well, in fact, there's no much difference between the two. Just two ways to tell qmake that you want an out-of-source build.

Comment: This is the most practical approach, since I just need to cd to the correct directory

Answer (score 1):

This is my proposal on how you can achieve the desired behavior. The idea is using two (or more) different Makefiles that will tell the `make` tool what to do. To create a set of Makefiles I would do this (roughly):

```
~ qmake -o ./normal/Makefile
```

to create a normal version, and:

```
~ qmake CONFIG+=sanitizer -o ./sanitizer/Makefile
```

to create a Makefile for sanitizer.
Now, if I want to build a normal version I call:

```
~ make -f ./normal/Makefile
```

and

```
~ make -f ./sanitizer/Makefile
```

to build an alternative version.
Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Yeah, that does the job.
I'm not accepting yet since this is not exactly what I asked, but I'll accept that in a couple of days if no other answer comes up.
Thanks !