# Qt Qmake automated build multiple variants of project with different options

Tags: qt, qmake

How would I go about automating compiling a project multiple times with different options? Preferably with QMake?

For example, compiling a "trial" version that literally excludes the pro features in the binary.

Now the toolchain is setup to output code archive, portable-zip and installer. Ideally I want the same again, but to a different name with other defines active.

This is on windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build multiple versions of a binary with qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818425/build-multiple-versions-of-a-binary-with-qmake)

Comment: @Matt So manually building via powershell is the only option?

Comment: I don't get what pwsh has to do with this.

Comment: @Matt right now qt creator is setting up the environments. I see that the best possible scenario is converting to cmake., which does more automations.